# Packagist vs. repo.magento.com

Tags: magento2.3

For installation of the community edition is there any benefit to installing from `repo.magento.com` instead of `Packagist`?

I see that there are over **20k** downloads of the community edition from packagist so I know it must be a pretty common practice, but the installation instructions recommend to install it from `repo.magento.com`.

I've searched through their documentation and couldn't find any reason why they want you to use their **repo instead of Packagist.**

**Is there something obvious I'm missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing from packagist you would still require access to repo.magento.com. The individual packages that make up `composer create-project magento/community-edition` are not available via packagist. You would also want to start with the project package and not the product.

I maintain a mirror of the Magento 2 packages - see details [here](https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/no-authentication-needed-magento-2-mirror.html) but I would still recommend using repo.magento.com for any production builds.

The main benefits are that you get your code from the source and repo.magento.com is also how you would obtain extensions via Magento's marketplace.

Comment: Hmm... I see the point about extensions but I think something may have changed recently with the dependencies maybe? I created a fresh project off Packagist and everything installed and seems to be working at expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! there are benefits, read below:

- If you have purchased Magento 2 extension on Magento Marketplace then you can install that package via **composer require**  from **repo.magento.com** server.

  - No need to download package zip file & extract in the server.
- By installing the extension by "composer" you can uninstall package code base & tables/attributes created by the extension also.

  - please refer M2 DevDocs on Uninstall modules: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

Regards.